# How to provide data using Sql Server Query for index.php in Yii2?

Tags: sql-server, yii2

I need to get data from SQL Server using query in *actionIndex* in controller send into *view*

default for get data from database(MySql) and send to view is like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new StudentsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

**but How if I need to get data using syntax SQL Server?**

this is my query

```
$totalCount = Yii::$app->db2->createCommand('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[students]')
            ->queryAll();
```

Comment: Do you have to use data from 2 different [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) in the application? If yes, you have to configure multiple DB application components if your application needs to access multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 ActiveDataProvider does take an optional parameter named 'db' through which you can send your own database connection parameter. So you can modify your StudentSearch model search function data provider to something like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => (new Query)->select('*')->from('students'),
     'key' => 'id',
     'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10
     ],
     'db' => \Yii::$app->db2
]);
```